# what should be the value of connection timeout in iis server for a ticketing application

Tags: iis, connection-timeout

I am working on an Application which is a ticketing tool,user log ticket corresponding to each task assign to them,there is Slow http post vulnerability in that which can be remove by manipulating connection timeout on iis server.
what should be the idea value of connection timeout for which i can solve that vulnerability?
please do help.

Comment: You need to experiment and find the number that works for you. This is not something anyone can help with

Comment: right,but still  could you please suggest me a suitable value which could work for me?

Comment: Whats the value now? double it?

Comment: right now its 120 seconds, i am plannin to reduce it to some extent..around 90 seconds or 70 seconds..would it be suitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security vulnerability can be fixed by updating the Limits settings for the web site.

1)Open IIS Manager

2)Select your site

3)On the Actions panel, click "Limits"

4)Set Connection time-out to 30

5)Check "Limit number of connections" and set the value to 1024.

[image]

6)Click OK

restart iis.

Comment: Thanks but how come you so sure that connection timeout should be 30 seconds only? do u have any authenticate site which can confirm this?

Comment: i need an authenticate site which can confirm me the value of connection timeout?

Comment: @withishan you could try to set the value based on your requirement. this is just an example. [link](https://blog.qualys.com/securitylabs/2011/11/02/how-to-protect-against-slow-http-attacks)

Comment: okay,means i can do hit n trial and which so ever value suits to my application, i apply that..okay?

Comment: @withishan yes. but first, you could try to set the value to 30 sec.

Comment: okay ,thanks for suggestion...i guess u r right coz 30 sec would be suitable as my application does'nt invlve too many users...its just a ticketing tool to log their task as a ticket